# Installing on CentOS 6.10

Tags: ffmpeg

We are trying to install ffmpeg and are following the instructions
at [FFMpeg installation in CentOS 6 - CentOS 7 with FFMpeg Static](https://www.binarycomputer.solutions/2018/install-ffmpeg-centos-6-centos-7)
(at Binary Computer Solutions, Inc). 
I have CentOS 6.10 kvm.

But when we run this commend it apparently does not intstall correctly because ffmpeg will not install.

`rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm`

These are the errors we get

```
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.1(CDIO_PARANOIA_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: x265-libs-1.9-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libass.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgmp.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: xvidcore-1.3.2-5.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_3_0_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libopenjpeg.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.8.15-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.1(CDIO_CDDA_1)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles —nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off building and installing from source.  Refer to the ffmpeg website for instructions on how to do it:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the && between the two rpm commands.  So it imports the key, but never installs the repository.

Putting the && between the two rpm commands, or running as two commands, will result in a successful install.

Try this:

```
rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro && rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm
```